# How to fetch embedded document list as flat array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model:

```
"client": {
    "title": { "type": "String", "required": true },
    "firstname": { "type": "String", "required": true },
    "lastname": { "type": "String", "required": true },
    "email": { "type": "String", "required": true, "index": { "unique": true } ...
    "purchases": [{ "amount": "Number", "productID": "String", "transactionDate": "Date"}],
    "complementaryNote": "String"
}
```

I want to fetch purchases as such:

```
[{ "amount": "Number", "productID": "String", "transactionDate": "Date"}, { "amount": "Number", "productID": "String", "transactionDate": "Date"} ...]
```

I use this query:

```
Client.find(pQuery).sort('-purchases.transactionDate').select('purchases').exec(function(err, pResults) {
            pResultCallback(pResults)})
```

Which gives this result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "569e50cf4895ced01aa55d9c",
        "purchases": [
            {
                "amount": 88761,
                "transactionDate": "2016-01-19T15:02:37.800Z",
                "productID": "Awesome Fresh Tuna",
                "_id": "569e50cf4895ced01aa55d9d"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "569e50df4895ced01aa589ae",
        "purchases": [
            {
                "amount": 66487,
                "transactionDate": "2016-01-19T14:02:19.777Z",
                "productID": "Licensed Cotton Keyboard",
                "_id": "569e50df4895ced01aa589af"
            }
        ]} ... ]
```

What I want to have instead is this:

```
[{
                    "amount": 88761,
                    "transactionDate": "2016-01-19T15:02:37.800Z",
                    "productID": "Awesome Fresh Tuna",
                    "_id": "569e50cf4895ced01aa55d9d"
                },
{
                    "amount": 66487,
                    "transactionDate": "2016-01-19T14:02:19.777Z",
                    "productID": "Licensed Cotton Keyboard",
                    "_id": "569e50df4895ced01aa589af"
                } ... ]
```

So I could eventually order them bt transaction date.

Thanks to anyone trying to help.